# Change data in DOM after successful fetch PUT

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I have an SPA in vanilla JS, using classes and modules.
The main idea is creating visits of customers and render them. When I fill in the form, data are sent to the server in JSON, after successful fetch, a visit card is created in the `#content` section.
The rendered card has two options: edit and delete. I made deletion without problems, I send DELETE, then just remove() the element onclick.
But I have some difficulties when editing the card.
I wrote the code to pop up modal form when click on the Edit button, and this form is filled with the card's data, so that the user can change them, click on Submit and send PUT to the server. The response is successful.
This is the edit form submit

```
edit(id) {
    const readData = document.querySelector('.form-edit');
    readData.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(e.target);
        const data = Array.from(formData.entries()).reduce((memo, pair) => ({
            ...memo,
            [pair[0]]: pair[1],
        }), {});
        editCard(data, id)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Something went wrong');
                }
            })

        document.querySelector(".closeBtnEdit").click();
    });
}
```

What I want, is to change the info of existing card in DOM after submitting the edited data.
This is the code of card rendering:

```
render(parent){
    this.elem.fullName.textContent = this.fullName;
    this.elem.purpose.textContent = `Purpose of the visit: ${this.purpose}`;
    this.elem.desc.textContent = `Description: ${this.desc}`;
    this.elem.priority.textContent = `Priority: ${this.priority}`;
    this.elem.date.textContent = `Visit Date: ${this.date}`;
    this.elem.delBtn.textContent = `Delete`;
    this.elem.editBtn.textContent = `Edit`;
}
```

Edit card API:

```
function editCard(newCard, cardId) {
return fetch(`${API}/${cardId}`,{
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newCard)
})
 }
```

Comment: Instead of `return response.json();` which essentially discards the server's reply, use it to update the card. With your current code, you have to do this *inside the response callback* you're passing to `.then()`

Comment: Please show what `editCard` looks like.

Comment: Heretic Monkey, added, thank you